# Venezuelans not pronouncing 's' at the end of words (seen in a show)

Tags: venezuela

I'm watching the new season of Jack Ryan which takes place in Venezuela. I noticed that the actors, when speaking Spanish, often drop the 's' at the ends of words such as gracias or pais. I was wondering if this is a Venezuelan accent. My knowledge of Spanish is rudimentary, and knowledge of accents across Spanish-speaking countries is non-existent, so I'm curious about this pattern.

Comment: Welcome to Spanish.SE! Something like this question has already been asked a few times. Please check if the "possible duplicated" linked above has an answer for you. If not, just say so.

Comment: I think that is a general feature of Caribbean Spanish. See this article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caribbean_Spanish

Answer (score -2):

Probably it's because they were speaking quickly, in Spain and other spanish speaking countries, we don't drop the 's' and it is pronounced. Maybe Venezuelan people tend to drop the 's' but it is not a common behaviour in Spanish. You should say "gracias" and "pais" as it sounds (with 's').

Comment: @walen Just in Andalucia (autonomous community in Southern Spain), I guess? I have already talked in Spanish with several Spanish people and have never noticed that.

Comment: @walen. Thanks for the links! My main point before was that it is not a feature of the whole of Spain, only some regions.

Comment: Well, with my answer I mean in general, is's not a common rule. You are talking about Andalucia for example, that has is own accent, but the truth is that if you talk regular Spanish, you pronounce the 's', so in the majority of the cases and moreover, if you want to sound natural, you should pronounce it.

Comment: There is no actual "pronunciation of *s*" - there's a phoneme /s/ that is pronounced in several ways (including not pronounced - zero) and there's several symbols that transcribe it.